# Переключение между блоками по клику

Tags: javascript

Есть 6 одинаковых блоков, на которых пользователь отвечает на вопрос. Как сделать, чтобы по клику на кнопку далее открывался следующий блок?

```
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.boxes');
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
});
boxes.forEach((e,idx)=>{
e[idx].classList.add('show');})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать добавлять классы с помощью глобальной переменной.

```js
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.boxes'),
btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

let i = 0;

function showPlease() {
  if (i !== 0) {
    boxes[i-1].classList.remove('show');
  }
  
  boxes[i].classList.add('show');
  i++;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', showPlease, false);
```

Comment: но разве все блоки не получают в таком случае класс show? ну то есть все будут видны и третьим параметром в функцию обработчик вы передали false, это зачем?

Comment: про `false` читайте на MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

сейчас исправлю, чтобы предыдущий скрывался

Answer (score 0):

```js
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.boxes');
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
btn.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.add("show")
})
})
```

```css
  .boxes {
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: hotpink;
  }
  .show {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
    <div class = "boxes show">
      <button class = "btn">Click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class = "boxes">
      <button class = "btn">Click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class = "boxes">
      <button class = "btn">Click me</button>
    </div>
    <div class = "boxes">
      <button class = "btn">Click me</button>
    </div>
```

Думаю вот так

Answer (score 0):

вот смотри:

```
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".boxes");
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");

const showPlease = () => {
  let i = 0;
  return () => {
    if (i !== 0 && i !== boxes.length) boxes[i - 1].classList.remove('show'); // если нужно чтобы последний блок тоже скрывался то условие `i !== boxes.length` нужно убрать
     boxes[i].classList.add('show'); 
    i++;
  }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', showPlease())
```

Работает.

Вот песочница [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Permogortsev/y79wx8kq/8/)

Comment: зачем нужно условие if (boxes[i - 1] && boxes[i - 1] !== boxes[5])?

Comment: удаляется класс `show` у не существующего нода если без этого условия. Ошибка.
Первый же элемент в массиве нулевой, а я беру `boxes[i - 1]`.

Comment: да.. дичь какая то, исправил

Comment: попробуй вместо `!==` чаще использовать `<` или `>`